# Java Script reading response of an URL into variable

Tags: javascript

I'm a java script newbie and I'm wonder how I can read the response from a URL into a variable.

Example:

Reading the weather information from NOAA into a java script variable.

```
var = http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/EDDB.TXT
```

Comment: You'll have to do ajax call

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 1):

"AJAX" is the technique to load data from a URL. jQuery makes AJAX easier (though you don't have to use it):

```
$.get('http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/EDDB.TXT', function(data) {
    // Do stuff with data here
});
```

Unfortunately, this probably won't work. Unless the web site you're downloading from does something special to allow it, which is not typical (look up CORS), you cannot use AJAX to load data from a different domain because the web browser will block it. For example, if your site is `example.com`, you cannot download from `weather.noaa.gov`.

An alternative would be to have server-side code in your web site that would download the content from the URL, acting as a proxy for that web site. Then your web page would download from your own server instead.

```
$.get('http://example.com/weatherStationData.php', function(data) {
    // Do stuff with data here
});
```